# npm WARN deprecated on node v14+ Nodejs on openshift cluster

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, npm, openshift

Please, any help would be appreciated.

I'm facing this issue for past 2 days. But then the docker image fails. I've update `chokidar`, `fsevents` doesn't update.

For the request I'm not sure what to do about `request`, `request`, `urix`, `resolve-url@`, `left-pad`, `core-js`.

```
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-30T11_34_14_726Z-debug.log
         The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Please let me know where do I do the changes. I'm new to it.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question.  The duplicate I flagged on your original question has almost the exact same error message and walks through the steps of installing `git` in your image.  If this doesn't resolve things for you, editing the original question to include a [mcve] – your `Dockerfile` and `package.json`, not just the error message – would improve it and make clear how it's different from the other one.

Comment: @DavidMaze but thne I've not found the solution working yet